# [CPU Cache]Different Cache Behaviour Between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, caching, cpu

I met an interview question about CPU cache line in Java. See the following codes:

```java
int[] a = new int[16 * 1024 * 1024 * 8];

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i] = 0;
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 16) {
    a[i] = 0;
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

output is:

```
60
55
```

The above 2 loops will cost approximately the same time. Because CPU cache line size is 64 bytes(16*int). Compared to the time cost of cache pipeline switching, the value assignment and the plus operation can be ignored.

I understand it, but when I tried such code in C++, wired thing happened.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int64_t current_time_ms() {
  return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(
             chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())
      .count();
}

const int N = 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 8;
int a[N];

int main() {
  auto start = current_time_ms();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
    a[i] = 0;
  }
  cout << current_time_ms() - start << "\n";

  start = current_time_ms();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 16) {
    a[i] = 0;
  }
  cout << current_time_ms() - start << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```sh
lianxin.wlx@mbp [18:50:00] [~/test] 
-> % g++ test.cc -O3 -std=c++11
lianxin.wlx@mbp [18:50:27] [~/test] 
-> % ./a.out 
237
81
```

The second loop cost much less time than the first. So why? What caused the difference between C++ and Java. Could anyone explain it?

Comment: I'm not sure this comparison makes much sense. In Java you have the JVM sitting in between the OS and the Java code and thus you could get all kinds of optimizations and other behavior in between. One of Java's goals is to abstract from hardware so I doubt hardware-centric optimization or tests make sense here.

Comment: Could you do the C++ version again, but running each test twice (giving 4 times)? Twice in the same run, not running the program twice.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that the C++ version takes any time at all.

Comment: @molbdnilo Code that writes to globals doesn't generally get optimised out.

Comment: If you stick a loop around the body of the C++ code and run it more than once, you will notice that the difference disappears after the first iteration. (And that Java can be Pretty Fast these days.)

Comment: Please use a proper microbenchmarking framework to make sure you are actually measuring JITed code instead of interpreted, and to make sure your compiler does not remove parts of the benchmark code.

Comment: Such a simple sequential pattern can be easily predicted by the CPU, and the spatial locality is enough to hide most of the prefetching latency (if not all). The JVM JIT already touches the array to 0-init it, so you have no page fault and most of the items are probably already hot. You have neither of these in C++, so get to really see an improvement.

Comment: @harold The result is 290ms, 70ms, 69ms, 71ms. OK I got it, maybe there is a page fault at first access.

Comment: I think you are all right, the problem is about page fault. Please post your comment as answers so that I can accept your answers.